# How to make a slicer dynamically change colour gradient in a column on a highest to smallest number basis

Tags: powerbi, daxstudio

I use power BI for analytics and in this case, I have a column that is filtered by a slicer. This column has values sorted in descending order tied to different states. on this column, I set a gradient color chart showing deepest color on highest value and becomes faint as the value decreases through this column. When a selection is made on the slicer, the column is filtered to show result of states with the corresponding values which will now be different from the values showing in the column before any selection was made on the slicer. The selection made shows result of numbers on this same column but ignores the color conditional formation of highest to lowest gradient. I want this column to display the color gradient of highest value to lowest as selections is made from the slicer that filters this column.

I have tried different options at the fx gradient settings withing power bi

[this picture shows the table where the color intensity is by the figures.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FWAE.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FWAE.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ9Ce.png  -

[This image is where i set the gradient for the colors in a descending order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FWAE.png)

[this image shows when a slicer is selected. the column has changed in figures and color.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scIpx.png)

Now you see the figures are in a descending order but i still have the gradient color of when no slicer was selected for this current selection. My question is how to make this table reflect color gradient like it showed when slicer was not selected, so this table with a selection will give me this numbers but the color gradient will be from deep saturation to faint as the numbers descends.

Comment: Please add a snip of before and after the slicer selection. And also add a snip of your conditional formatting settings. Edit your question to include these.